# Does the Da Vinci line of 3D printers come with a heated bed?

Tags: heated-bed, hardware

I'm now currently looking at getting my next 3D printer, after my success with the Prusa i3 Reprap Build, and I have had my eyes on the Da Vinci line of printers for some time now.

What I want to know is, does this line of 3D printers include a heated bed? Or does it come with a stock aluminum bed?

Comment: Literally the very first google return for "[Does the Da Vinci line of 3D Printers come with a heated bed?](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=Does+the+Da+Vinci+line+of+3D+Printers+come+with+a+heated+bed)" is *The Pro has adjustable heat settings for the nozzle and the aluminum print bed...*

Comment: I did do a google search about the Da Vinci Printers and their heated beds. But I wasn't sure if an aluminium bed is the same as a heated bed

Comment: Are you sure you want a DaVinci?  They are the best seller on Amazon, but they have chipped filament which you either have to buy theirs or hack around.  Nothing wrong with a razor and blades business model if you like the blades and are willing to pay extra for them, but there are so many options out there that are more DIY friendly and isn't that the 3d printer ethos anyway?

Comment: I am sure I want a Da Vinci 3D Printer. I do understand that the DIY kits offer more freedom than pre-built kits. But due to time constraints and requirements, I need a 3D printer that is ready straight out of the box

Comment: You can flash several of the models with Repetier firmware allowing you to do whatever and use whatever filament, there are also several workarounds if you want to use your own filament without changing the firmware.  I have a DaVinci 2.0A with both hotends replaced with E3D versions.  I use Repetier on it and I send my prints to it using a wireless SD card.  Repetier firmware can be found here, read all the instructions before doing the flash - https://github.com/luc-github/Repetier-Firmware-0.92

Comment: @GipsyD While this is off topic, you may want to take a look at the selection of printers offered by Monoprice.  They offer a comparable level of "Out of the box" readiness at a similar price point, but without the long term commitment to DaVinci filament.  (I strongly considered buying a DaVinci printer before I discovered Monoprice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The Da Vinci Duo 2 (most common one) has a heated bed.